# Converting an array of type T to an array of type I where T implements I in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, ienumerable

I am trying to accomplish something in C# that I do easily in Java. But having some trouble.
I have an undefined number of arrays of objects of type T.
A implements an interface I.
I need an array of I at the end that is the sum of all values from all the arrays.
Assume no arrays will contain the same values.

This Java code works.

```
ArrayList<I> list = new ArrayList<I>();
for (Iterator<T[]> iterator = arrays.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    T[] arrayOfA = iterator.next();
    //Works like a charm
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayOfA));
}

return list.toArray(new T[list.size()]);
```

However this C# code doesn't:

```
List<I> list = new List<I>();
foreach (T[] arrayOfA in arrays)
{
    //Problem with this
    list.AddRange(new List<T>(arrayOfA));
    //Also doesn't work
    list.AddRange(new List<I>(arrayOfA));
}
return list.ToArray();
```

So it's obvious I need to somehow get the array of `T[]` into an `IEnumerable<I>` to add to the list but I'm not sure the best way to do this? Any suggestions?

EDIT: Developing in VS 2008 but needs to compile for .NET 2.0.

Comment: Invalid argument in both cases.
new List<I>(arrayOfA) - fails
list.AddRange(new List<T>(arrayOfA)) - fails

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up with. The answer from Dan also works well. Not sure why the direct cast AddRange((I[]) arrayOfA) won't work when Thorsten's example does work fine?

Comment: I think you can do that in Java because of type erasure (bleh!). Behind the curtains, ArrayList<T> is actually ArrayList<?> and ArrayList<I> is also ArrayList<?>.

Comment: See my answer. You need to restrict T to reference types to get the implicit conversion from T[] to I[].

Comment: By the way. You _can_ use Linq while targeting .NET 2.0. Look into Linqbridge: http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that C# doesn't support [co-variance](http://weblogs.asp.net/astopford/archive/2006/12/28/c-generics-covariance.aspx) (at least not until C# 4.0, I think) in generics so implicit conversions of generic types won't work.

You could try this:

```
List<I> list = new List<I>();
foreach (T[] arrayOfA in arrays)
{
    list.AddRange(Array.ConvertAll<T, I>(arrayOfA, t => (I)t));
}
return list.ToArray();
```

---

For anyone that strumbles across this question and is using .NET 3.5, this is a slightly more compact way of doing the same thing, using Linq.

```
List<I> list = new List<I>();
foreach (T[] arrayOfA in arrays)
{
    list.AddRange(arrayOfA.Cast<I>());
}
return list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Like that, it's very elegant. Had to give a few +1 but ended up using this. Thanks. Still confused about Throsten's answer. Not sure why it won't work in my example yet his code works fine?

Comment: Adrian: perhaps your T is a value type?  Array type covariance only works on reference types. In your example, try casting like this:  (IEnum<I>)(I[])arrayOfA -- does that work?

Comment: Aha! Bingo. T is a value type, I guess I should have specified that up front. Learning lots of new stuff today. Unfortunately though your suggestion hasn't helped, still sticking with the answer above.

Answer (score 7):

Edited for 2.0; it can become:

```
static void Main() {
    IEnumerable<Foo[]> source = GetUndefinedNumberOfArraysOfObjectsOfTypeT();
    List<IFoo> list = new List<IFoo>();
    foreach (Foo[] foos in source) {
        foreach (IFoo foo in foos) {
            list.Add(foo);
        }
    }
    IFoo[] arr = list.ToArray();
}
```

How about (in .NET 3.5):

```
I[] arr = src.SelectMany(x => x).Cast<I>().ToArray();
```

To show this in context:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;
interface IFoo { }
class Foo : IFoo { //  A implements an interface I
    readonly int value;
    public Foo(int value) { this.value = value; }
    public override string ToString() { return value.ToString(); }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // I have an undefined number of arrays of objects of type T
        IEnumerable<Foo[]> source=GetUndefinedNumberOfArraysOfObjectsOfTypeT();
        // I need an array of I at the end that is the sum of
        // all values from all the arrays. 
        IFoo[] arr = source.SelectMany(x => x).Cast<IFoo>().ToArray();
        foreach (IFoo foo in arr) {
            Console.WriteLine(foo);
        }
    }
    static IEnumerable<Foo[]> GetUndefinedNumberOfArraysOfObjectsOfTypeT() {
        yield return new[] { new Foo(1), new Foo(2), new Foo(3) };
        yield return new[] { new Foo(4), new Foo(5) };
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, what's the purpose of the SelectMany there? You beat me by seconds on the .Cast, so +1 from me :-)

Comment: The SelectMany is effectively concatenating the elements of the arrays.

Comment: Awesomecake, I think I'll add that one to the list of cool things I didn't know about LINQ. Ta fellas

Comment: Sorry, should have specified that it needs to compile for 2.0. But as Dan says some very cool LINQ stuff there

Comment: The Cast<IFoo>() is unnecessary. It would be necessary if you were assigning to IEnumerable<IFoo> instead of IFoo[] (until C# 4.0, when it becomes unnecessary there also).

Comment: (Although of course it really should have been necessary for arrays as they are mutable!)

Comment: It is required for arrays of value-type objects ;-p

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have tried

```
list.AddRange((I[])arrayOfA);
```

already?

**EDIT** In reply to your comment saying that my suggestion wouldn't work: I successfully ran this code just a minute ago:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tester
{
    class Program
    {
        private interface I
        {
            string GetValue();
        }

        private class A : I
        {
            private string value;

            public A(string v)
            {
                value = v;
            }

            public string GetValue()
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<I> theIList = new List<I>();

            foreach (A[] a in GetAList())
            {
                theIList.AddRange((I[])a);
            }

            foreach (I i in theIList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.GetValue());
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<A[]> GetAList()
        {
            yield return new [] { new A("1"), new A("2"), new A("3") };
            yield return new [] { new A("4") };
        }
    }
}
```

Or did I just muss a requirement?

Comment: I fail to see why the above should not work. I've edited my answer and posted some sample code that works.

Comment: No, can't see how that works because it certainly doesn't work on my example and yet your code compiles and runs fine.
As far as I understood you can never cast from T[] to I[] even if T:I. Excuse me for doubting, I must apologise!

Comment: No need to apologize! I'm just curious why your code doesn't work while my code does. I always thought being able to cast from T[] to I[] is part of polymorphism if T implements I? Also, I'm even doing the opposite all the time, for example casting from `DataRow[]` to `TypedDataSetRow[]`.

Comment: Covariant array conversions "work" in that they are legal, but they are broken in that doing so creates situations in which type safety is compromised. They are legal in C# and Java; I wish they had never been made legal in either. See my article on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx

Comment: There is a suggestion above that the reason this doesn't work in my case is that T is infact a struct (or value type). I am assuming this to be correct? Perhaps you can confirm? (Sorry I didn't mention that in the original question)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a generic constraint

where T:I

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem here is that generics doesn't realize that T implements I. It might work to declare explicitly T : I.

Also you could do a for loop and add your T objects one at a time instead of using AddRange.

Answer (score 1):

The type structure of c# does not currently support this (treating the `Foo<T>` as a `Foo<I>` if X : I) this is termed covariance on I.

The underlying framework does, and [c# 4.0 is adding support for it](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx)

As such explicit casts are required, Marc's answer being the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code you are not adding the arrayOfA to the result list:

```
List<I> list = new List<I>();
foreach (T[] arrayOfA in arrays)
    list.AddRange(arrayOfA);

return list.ToArray();
```

However, if you are using .NET 3.5 you can do this with LINQ:

```
return (from arrayOfA in arrays
        from element in arrayOfA
        select element as I).ToArray();
```

Or using LINQ methods:

```
return arrays.SelectMany(arrayOfA => arrayOfA.Cast<I>()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, well spotted. I think everyone got the gist of the question none-the-less. Fixed and a +1 for you for sharp eyes :) (Unf no LINQ so couldn't use your solution.)

Comment: The non-LINQ code should work for you, none the less, as Rasmus says, arrays of reference objects are covariant in C#.

Comment: I am assuming the non-LINQ code doesn't work for the same reason I cant cast form T[] to I[]. At this stage it appears this is because T is actually a value type. BAck to school for me!

Answer (score 0):

[Arrays of reference objects are covariant in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) (the same is true for Java).

From the name, I guess that your T is a generic and not a real type, so you have to restrict it to a reference type in order to get the implicit conversion from T[] to I[].

Try this:

```
public static I[] MergeArrays<T,I>(IEnumerable<T[]> arrays) 
    where T:class,I
{
    List<I> list = new List<I>();
    foreach(T[] array in arrays){
        list.AddRange(array);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```