# In C#, what is the proper way to cast an ICollection<X> to ICollection<Y>?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

For example:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    //...

    ICollection<IFoo> Children { get; }

    //...
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    //...

    public ICollection<Foo> Children { get; private set; }

    //...

    public ICollection<IFoo> IFoo.Children
    {
        get
        {
            return Children; // Obviously wrong datatype, how do I cast this?
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

So how do I correctly implement `IFoo.Children`? I tried `Children.Cast<IFoo>` but this returns an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to think this through. If this cast would work, code would be allowed to add a completely different class object to your collection, one that implements IFoo but is otherwise completely unrelated to Foo. Your collection will now no longer be a collection of Foo. That of course can't be permitted. IEnumerable<> is fine, that can't alter the collection. ICollection<> is not.

The only possible way to get what you want is to create a copy of the collection.  Like a `List<IFoo>`.  You'll of course pay the perf for that.  And can't easily see changes to that list, that's fixable.  But you'll still have the fundamental problem that client code modifying that list still allows adding or removing objects that you don't know how to deal with.

Comment: Good point. That means it would have to be immutable in order to do this. What would be the best immutable collection type for that?

Answer (score 3):

Try `Children.Cast<IFoo>().ToList()`.

Comment: That would compile and work, but it's not a cast and would actually have a runtime price.

Comment: @Matt `ICollection` is not covariant whereas other interfaces such as `IEnumerable` are. I'm afraid there's no better way.

Comment: What's the best thing to use instead of `ICollection` then? I want a collection type that can be added to, removed from, etc.

Comment: @Matt I would use `IList`.

Comment: Well, one better way (in terms of performance) would be a wrapper class which implements `ICollection<IFoo>` directly, bit cumbersome perhaps.

Comment: Then how would I cast it if it were `IList`?

Comment: `IList` is not covariant either, but I still prefer it over `ICollection` because it has the notion of index.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602400/how-to-convert-ilistsomeobject-to-ilistisomeinterface-where-someobject-imple)